# Create image from Friend's profile images - Facebook/PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an application where I'll create an image from the application user's friends profile image.

[image: This is what i want]

In this image there are 4 photos of friends, I want to create a new [single] image in that image all of the images will be pasted.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i get your question right you will first need all their pictures, try the following:

```
$facebook_friends = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' .
$_SESSION['cookie']['access_token']), true);
$friends = $facebook_friends['data'];

foreach($friends as $key => $values){
    echo '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$value['id'].'/picture" />';
}
```

Comment: Check out the following php methods: imagecreatefromjpeg, getimagesize() and imagejpeg. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagecopymerge()` function to add the four `jpg` profile images in a single image. Then, use the graph `API` to get user friend .

```
 imagecopymerge($mainimg, $friends, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);
```

Here `mainimg` is representing your Background image. You can build an individual image in php using `GD` functions.